# Ipad ( 1 ): safari keep crashing in my "supersized" slideshow

Tags: jquery, image, ipad, safari, crash

i have a big problem.
I'm fixing a website to be surfable in a nice way also with mobile devices, but i am having a very big trouble when i visit some galleries with APPLE IPAD 1.
the site is www.morlotti.com, and the pages i have big issues are the galleries inside the wedding portfolio and in photographers.
check for example

http://www.morlotti.com/mobile/country-chic

images are 800px wide saved at 6 quality for web... every file is something like 90kb... i don't know what to do... i'm a bit desperate

Comment: i don't have any problems with iphone4, 4s, ipad2

Comment: anybody knows a solution ? :\

Comment: so.. uhmm... it seems there isn't a proper solution for this !_!

Comment: Can I see how you are calling your images and your settings?  I'm not having a problem with iPad, ipad2, iPhone 3g, iPhone 4...

Answer (score 0):

Try add to youre images container CSS:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

And to Youre slider js file:

```
$(window).focusout(function() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
     location.reload();
     }
 });
```